# Sonar pmd analysis is taking more time while running from Build Forge

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, pmd

I am using sonar 3.4.1. & using IBM Build forge tool as C.I tool and it is taking 45 mins to complete the entire build process which is not unacceptable as my LOC 18k only.

If i run sonar analysis without build forge for the same project , it is completed within few minutes .

From the sonar logs i can see that it is taking more time while running the PMD section . If i remove some of the jdbc and hibernate based rules, the time taken is getting reduced 20 minutes.  what is going on inside PMD anaylsis .

Comment: Your question is rather unclear and as such it is very difficult to understand what is going on and so it is impossible to answer to you. Please post your logs, be precise about your findings : which rules did you deactivate ?  Precise also the versions of the java and PMD plugin. 

Finally, the SonarQube version you are using is quite old and as such I would recommend as a first move to upgrade your version of the platform and the java and PMD plugins.

Comment: i have removed these rule : HibernateBasicRule
JdbcBasicRule
HibernateStmtRule
KeepSQLOutOfCode
AvoidThrowsSQLException



AvoidHardCodeFilePath
AvoidMultipleInstanceOf
CharInstantiation
LoggerHasWrongCategory
ParseIntMightThrowNumberFormatException
NonMatchingIteratorInstance

Comment: Please precise the versions you are using. Post a log.

Comment: Sonar 3.4.1 , sonar-pmd-plugin-1.1.jar, java 1.5, and i have disabled the below rules, now pmd analysis completed in few minutes.      AvoidHardCodeFilePath
 AvoidMultipleInstanceOf
 AvoidSystemExitToTerminate
 AvoidThrowsSQLException
 AvoidUsingArraysCopyOf 
 CharInstantiation
 ParseIntMightThrowNumberFormatException
 MembersMustBePrivate
 NonMatchingIteratorInstance
 Use StringBuilder Insteadof StringBuffer 
 UseBufferForFileOperation
 UseForEachOrIterator 
 UseLoggingMechanismToPrintException
 UsePreparedStatementInLoop
 Basic Hibernate Rules
 Basic JDBC Rules
 Hibernate Statement Rules

Comment: Honestly those versions are beginning to get quite old, so I would recommend first to upgrade your versions before spending too much time investigating. ( the version of the pmd plugin you mention is not even tagged on github : https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-pmd )